# How to fix the localhost:8080 (502 Bad Gateway) problem

Tags: tomcat8

I downloaded Tomcat 8 on my Mac and I started it up but when I go to the browser and enter localhost:8080 it gives me a `502 Bad gateway` error that says:

```
Socks5ProtocolException("SOCKS5 mode failure: SocksError('Invalid SOCKS version. Expected 0x05, got 0x47',)",)
```

how can I fix this problem?

It was working fine but after a few days, it started to give me this error. is it okay to just change the default port o for example 8081? or I will need that 8080 port at some point?

thanks in advance.

Comment: did you find the solution? As a workaround (which fails during production) I change the port of the application to other port number like you suggested.  But during production to AWS, I get failure.  Just wondering if you fixed this error - we seem to be having the exact issue.  Im using macOS.